# gcc compilation with dark moon cygwin

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gcc, cygwin

I am learning to use bash on Windows, I installed dark moon cygwin and I want to compile "old code" with gcc on windows.  I can compile my code and run it in dark moon, but when I put it on another computer, it doesn’t run my executable, what did I miss to do please? I searched and wondered if this wouldn’t come from trying to run my executable out of dark moon, does that mean that my code can only be run from a cygwin environment?

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin provides a POSIX API environment on Windows, so that software written with that API in mind (like Linux or BSD software) can easily be ported over.

That environment is provided by the [Cygwin.dll](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.api.everything). Your software is being linked against that DLL, which turns POSIX function calls (like open, read, or write) into appropriate Windows function calls.

On a system without Cygwin installed, that DLL does not exist, so the software won't work.

So either your software requires Cygwin to be installed, or you [use the MinGW tool suite](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.programming.win32-no-cygwin), a different compiler set that doesn't target the Cygwin.dll and creates "real" Windows executables. Of course, then you don't have access to the POSIX API in your software...

Comment: So I have the choice between installing cygwin or installing the Mingw suite of tools. I read on this site: https://dark-moon-x.github.io/DarkMoon/ that dark moon gnu cygwin was portable, so it can be launched on any computer without installation.  Does this mean that I just have to run darkmoon and my executable application will launch and what do you think is the best solution?

Comment: @TED: Basically the code you are trying to compile makes the decision for you. MinGW is WinAPI, Cygwin is POSIX.

Comment: If you're planning to distribute Cygwin DLLs, make sure to comply with the licensing terms: https://cygwin.com/licensing.html